# Tab usage in flex with bootstrap 5

Tags: flexbox, bootstrap-5

I have a page with 3 sections on my html code and I divided each section into three with bootstrap card. These are called card-1, card-2 and card-3. My page has the following items:

- At the top there is a header information called "pageFilterId".
- In the middle is the Bootstrap 5 navbar tab panel and it's called "pageTabId".
- At the bottom, there is a section with informational notes and it is called "pageBottomId".

Card contents can change within the page or card heights can change depending on clicks. What I want is for the tab-pane content in the middle bootstrap tab panel to fill the entire page.

However, if you are using an iframe inside a tab-pane in card. tab-pane does not fully occupy the remaining height of the page. I wanted to do it with d-flex and flex-column but tab-pane doesn't seem to detect them.

Code: https://codepen.io/omerix/full/mdQyBzN

```js
function jsFrameLoad(frameId, dataHref) {
  var currentSrc = $('#' + frameId).attr('src');
  console.log('jsFrameLoad', currentSrc, dataHref);

  if (currentSrc !== dataHref) {
    $('#' + frameId).attr('src', dataHref);
  }
}

function jsToggle(selector) {
  var element = document.querySelector(selector);
  if (element.classList.contains('d-none')) {
    element.classList.remove('d-none');
  } else {
    element.classList.add('d-none');
  }
}
```

```css
.divFull {
  background-color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  /*min-height:540px;*/
}

.iframeFull {
  background-color: purple;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  /*min-height:400px;*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div id='formDiv' class="container-wrap bg-danger flex-grow-1 d-flex flex-column" style='min-height:100vh;'>
  <form id='formId' post="test.php">
    <!-- card1 -->
    <div id='pageFilterId' class="card m-2 shadow-sm bg-primary">

      <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center py-1 px-3 bg-white border-0">
        <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
        <div>
          <button onclick="jsToggle('#filtreId')">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card-body" id='filtreBody'>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-body-secondary">Card subtitle</h6>
        Filter Body
      </div>

      <div class="card-footer">
        <div class="btn-group">
          Buttons
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- card1/ -->

    <div id='pageTabId' class="cardx mx-2 shadow-sm flex-grow-1 d-flex flex-column" style='background-color:#ff0000;'>
      <div id='tabHeader' class="card-headerx d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center py-1 px-3 border-0 bg-white">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tab1Panel">Tab-1</a>
          </li>
          
          <li class="nav-item d-none d-lg-block">
            <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tab2Panel" onclick="jsFrameLoad('tab2PanelFrame','/a.htm')">Tab-2</a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item d-none d-lg-block">
            <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tab3Panel" onclick="jsFrameLoad('tab3PanelFrame','/b.htm');">Tab-3</a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item d-none d-lg-block">
            <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tab4Panel">Tab-4</a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item d-none d-lg-block">
            <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tab5Panel" onclick="jsFrameLoad('tab5PanelFrame','/c.htm');">Tab-5</a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item d-none d-lg-block">
            <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tab6Panel">Tab-6</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <div>
          Settings Tab
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id='tabBody' class="tab-content p-0 m-0" style='background-color:#ff8000;'>
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tab1Panel" style='background-color:#00bfff;'>
          <h6>1.row </h6>
          <h6>2.row </h6>
          <h6>3.row </h6>
          <h6>4.row </h6>
          <h6>5.row </h6>
          <h6>6.row </h6>
          <h6>7.row </h6>
          <h6>8.row </h6>
          <h6>9.row </h6>
          <h6>10.row </h6>
          <h6>11.row </h6>
          <h6>12.row </h6>
          <h6>13.row </h6>
          <h6>14.row </h6>
          <h6>15.row </h6>
          <h6>16.row </h6>
          <h6>17.row </h6>
          <h6>18.row </h6>
          <h6>19.row </h6>
          <h6>20.row </h6>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade d-flex flex-column flex-fill" id="tab2Panel" style='background-color:#00bfff;'>
          <div class='bg-primary'>Tab-2 Head</div>
          <div class='bg-info flex-grow-1'>
            <iframe id="tab2PanelFrame" name="tab2PanelFrame" class='iframeFull' frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
          </div>
          <div class='bg-primary'>Tab-2 Footer</div>
        </div>

        <div id="tab3Panel" class="tab-pane fade" style='background-color:#00bfff;'>
          <div class='divFull'>
            <iframe id="tab3PanelFrame" name="tab3PanelFrame" class='iframeFull' frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="tab5Panel" class="tab-pane fade" style='background-color:#00bfff;'>
          <div class='divFull'>
            <iframe id="tab5PanelFrame" name="tab5PanelFrame" class='iframeFull' frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab4Panel" style='background-color:#00bfff;'>
          <div class='divFull' id='divFull'>
            ...
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="tab-pane fade bg-success" id="tab6Panel" style='background-color:#00bfff;'>
          <div class='divFull'>
            <textarea class='tinymce'>
                                Html Code
                            </textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- tab-content -->

      <div id='tabFooter' class="card-footerx p-0 m-0 bg-info">
        Card Footer Info
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- card2 -->

    <!-- card3 -->
    <div id='pageBottomId' class="card m-2 bg-success">
      Html Footer
    </div>
    <!-- card3/ -->

  </form>
</div>
<!-- formDiv -->
```

Problems:

- tab-pane does not auto-expand based on remaining space on the page.
- In tabs, the iframe goes over the html footer by the user.
- When the size of card-1 and card-3 changes in the actions on the page, the middle panel (card-2) does not expand.